# ruamel.yaml How to quote strings containing colon?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using `ruamel.yaml` in python, I'm running into an issue where I dump my yaml, but strings containing colons are not quotes. Does anyone know how to resolve?

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

yaml = YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False

d = {"example": "2:1"}
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

yields

```
example: 2:1
```

when I'm expecting

```
example: '2:1'
```

edit: So the above response appears the response is valid yaml (https://yaml.org/spec/). Something in my pipeline appears to be mishandling it along the way.

Is it possible to force ruamel.yaml to quote values?

Answer (score 1):

If you have elements in your pipeline that assume  YAML 1.1 (e.g. if they are based on PyYAML) then your `2:1` is interpreted as a sexagesimal. In that case you should add a line after your `YAML()` instantiation:

```
 yaml = YAML()
 yaml.version = (1, 1) # you can also use: yaml.version = "1.1"
```

But this will add an  explicit `%YAML 1.1` header line to your document.

Instead of adding the version line, you can explicitly quote this string by using

```
 from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as DQS

 d = {"example": DQS("2:1")}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This addresses the nuisance I was dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out something in my pipeline was assuming YAML 1.1. The issue wasn't that `2:1` wasn't valid YAML in 1.1 or any YAML version, it was that in YAML 1.1 `2:1` is interpreted as base 60 and not as a string.

Basically this was a non-issue. `ruamel.yaml` handled everything correctly.